# MVC3 remote database access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, windows, asp.net-mvc-3

since last week I've been busy with mvc3. I'm new to the whole .net scene, the only programming experience I have is C++.

What I'm trying to do is make a CMS using mvc3. The assignment is to replace the current CMS (Umbraco) and implement a new one. The existing database sits in a windows 2008 R2 server, and it is a MSSQL server database.

The problem is that I have no idea where to look for something like this, everything I find is either about a local database within the solution or stuff I don't understand a thing about. If someone could direct me towards some tutorials that cover my problem I'd be very happy :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of tutorials here and a good place to get started with ASP.NET MVC: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, I have looked at most of those already, and I have succesfully recreated the webstore application ([link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1)) wich was very helpful. But it doesn't cover remote database acces.

Comment: @Kevin, in part 4 you have created classes that perform data access using the local SQL Server CE edition. All you have to do is change the connection string in your web.config and point it to the remote SQL database server. This way it will no longer use the App_Data folder but it will connect to this server.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Hmm, I changed my connection string to <add name="Boomerweb" connectionString="Data Source=109.109.121.12| DataDirectory=C:\boomerweb\www\SQL| Boomerweb.sql| Initial Catalog=myDataBase| User Id=myUsername| Password=myPassword|" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/> I am aware that this shouldn't work, because the databases don't match. But it still fetches the data from the local database. It's probably something really stupid I'm missing here :). I'm also looking at [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618472), wich looks promising.

Comment: @Kevin, take a look how a connection string to a reomte database should look like: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 You specify the name of the SQL Server (or its IP address), the name of the database you are willing to connect to and the credentials to authenticate. Also you need to change the provider name to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and the quick replies. I think I can get a lot further with his. It's really annoying I can't +1 you :(.

Comment: @Kevin, if this answer was helpful make sure you [mark it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.